# time download can't convert to GMT timing

Tags: java, datetime

my concept for download file is as below:
if the adapter restart at 7.00am,
first time download will be starting from 00:00:00 until 7am..
after 5 minute will download again, so is the download timing will be 6.58am to 7.05am.
Timezome will be different, like Asia/Singapore,Asia/Hong_Kong etc..
but this timezone need convert to GMT for some purpose.

the below is my coding

```
private String TIME_ZONE_ID = "America/New_York";
private final String TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT = "Etc/GMT";
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (sessionFactory.fileServer == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("sessionfactory.fileServer is null");
    // hsding@debug
    out.println("d> 2.1");

    while (true && isStarted) {
        try {
            if (!isConnected) {
                out.println("d> 2.2");
                openTransport(); // Connect
            }// end if
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.println(expMsg + " run():" + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            boolean isValid = getTokenValidity();
            if (isConnected) {
                // boolean isValid = getTokenValidity();

                out.println("Is Token Valid = [" + isValid + "]");
                if (isValid) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < garrNewsFilterCriteria.length; i++) {
                            giCurrSubscribeSeqNo = i;

                            // add in keep track of last download time. hsding@debug@2016041x
                            if (garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime[i] == null) {
                                out.println("garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime= " + garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime[i]);
                                garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime[i] = getStartDateTime(true);
                            } else {
                                out.println("garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime2= " + garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime[i]);
                                garrLastNewsSubscribeStartTime[i] = getStartDateTime();
                            }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    out.println("Token not valid!!!");
                    isConnected = false;
                }
            } else
                isConnected = false;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(expMsg + " run():" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
private XMLGregorianCalendar getStartDateTime() {
    return getStartDateTime(false);
}

private XMLGregorianCalendar getStartDateTime(boolean startFromZeroHour) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = null;
    try {
        xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // hsding@debug@20160419. enhance on the retrieve time FROM and TO.
    // Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Eastern"));

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    out.println("D> now 0=" + now);
    if (startFromZeroHour) {
        // ??????
        now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    } else {
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // pre offset the second to zero for easy the polling job in future.
        int fallback_prev_N_second = (int) (SLEEP_TIME * 2) / 1000 * -1;
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, fallback_prev_N_second);
    }

    out.println("D> now 1=" + now);
    now.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT));
    // hsding@debug@2016041x
    out.println("D> now 2=" + now);

    xmlCal.setDay(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    xmlCal.setMonth(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    xmlCal.setYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    xmlCal.setTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    out.println("D> xmlCal=" + xmlCal);

}

private XMLGregorianCalendar getEndDateTime() {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = null;
    int iDay = 0;
    int iMonth = 0;
    try {
        xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    // out.println("News Retrieve [End Time] =" + xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());

    // hsding@debug@20160419. enhance on the retrieve time FROM and TO.
    // Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Eastern"));

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    out.println("D> End time =" + now);
    now.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE_ID_TRKD_DEFAULT));
    out.println("D> End time2 =" + now);
    xmlCal.setDay(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    // xmlCal.setDay(12);
    // We do a +1 below because XMLGregorianCalendar goes from 1 to 12
    // while Calendar.MONTH goes from 0 to 11 !!!
    xmlCal.setMonth(now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    // xmlCal.setMonth(1);
    xmlCal.setYear(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    xmlCal.setTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 59);
    out.println("D> End time xmlcal  =" + xmlCal);
    return xmlCal;
}
 private void getNewsHeaderFromReuters(String sParam01, String sParam02, XMLGregorianCalendar xmlParam03) throws Exception {

try{
        RetrieveHeadlineMLRequest1 headlineRequest = new RetrieveHeadlineMLRequest1();

        NewsRequest newsRequest = new NewsRequest();

        Filter filter = new Filter();

        MetaDataConstraint constraint = new MetaDataConstraint();



        newsRequest.setStartTime(xmlParam03);

        newsRequest.setEndTime(getEndDateTime());


        out.println("News Retrieve [START Time]=" + newsRequest.getStartTime());
        out.println("News Retrieve [END Time]=" + newsRequest.getEndTime());

        headlineRequest.setHeadlineMLRequest(newsRequest);
        RetrieveHeadlineMLResponse1 headlineResponse;

        int i = 0;

        try {
            String sNewsID = "";
            boolean isProcess = true;

            headlineResponse = newsPort.retrieveHeadlineML1(headlineRequest);
            out.println("SOAP request :  " + messageDumper.nextMessage());
            out.println("SOAP response :  " + messageDumper.nextMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println(expMsg + " getNewsHeaderFromReuters()" + e.getMessage());
        isConnected = false;
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

i use example for present my problem:
When the adapter restart on 2017-02-18 7am on Singapore timing, After convert to GMT  Start time is 2017-02-18 00:00:00, but end time is 2017-02-17 11:50:34.
this is wrong de..

When the adapter restart after 2017-02-18 8 am on Singapore timing, After convert to GMT  Start time is 2017-02-18 00:00:00, but end time is 2017-02-18 00:05:34( up to the timing convert to GMT). but it is correct..

if i no convert to GMT, all timing is correct , but i don't wan this answer cause it will affected some data, so it need convert to GMT first.

Please kindly advice what wrong for my coding...

Thanks

Regards
Sharon

Comment: Can you cut this example down to an [mcve]? There is lots of code here unrelated to *get time -- convert time -- display time*, which is surely all you need

Comment: Timezone conversion is easy if you use a sensible time API, like `java.time`. `java.util.Calendar` is *not* a sensible time API.